# Invoking external shell application through RubyCocoa

Tags: objective-c, ruby, cocoa, ruby-cocoa

How would I invoke an external application through the RubyCocoa bridge? I read something about NSTask, yet I have no idea how this should be translated in RubyCocoa. My goal is to have an **IB_action** to trigger a method which will run a terminal application with some parameters, i.e. `ls -p $mydir`, where mydir comes from an **IB_outlet** such as an Textfield. Any directions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is invoked using ` quotes and #{} structure for variable

```
`ls -p #{mydir}`
```

Comment: Works like a charm, awesomeness!